# GridView height spacing

Tags: android, android-xml, android-gridview

For some reason I dont understand, there is a spacing between my grid's rows while I clearly have set vertical spacing to 0. I tried playing with different width and height settings in both my grid's xml and in the image's xml (the grid component).

this is what i have:

[image]

and this is what i want:

[image]

you can see grid xml and the image xml below:

grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:columnWidth="144dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: wow. such a simple answer and I've been searching for hours -_-;
thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess follwoing one of the optins will solve ut issue :

`set imageview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);  in adapter`

Or

```
<GridView
        android:stretchMode="none">
</GridView>
```

Comment: thanks :). the first worked. (I guess u are the one who commented and removed the comment?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MyGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```